# Rails 3 nested routes form problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've been going through all of the other questions and answers to no avail.

My form starts like such:

```
<% @new_article = company.news.new %>
<%= form_for(@new_article, {:url => [company, @new_article]}) do |news_form| %>
```

The error is this:

```
Routing Error

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"news", :company_id=>nil, :id=>2}
```

Rake routes says this:

```
           company_news_index GET    /companies/:company_id/news(.:format)                                        
                                         {:action=>"index", :controller=>"news"} 
                              POST   /companies/:company_id/news(.:format)                                        
                                         {:action=>"create", :controller=>"news"}
             new_company_news GET    /companies/:company_id/news/new(.:format)                                    
                                         {:action=>"new", :controller=>"news"}
            edit_company_news GET    /companies/:company_id/news/:id/edit(.:format)                               
                                         {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"news"}
                 company_news GET    /companies/:company_id/news/:id(.:format)                                    
                                         {:action=>"show", :controller=>"news"}
                              PUT    /companies/:company_id/news/:id(.:format)                                    
                                         {:action=>"update", :controller=>"news"}
                              DELETE /companies/:company_id/news/:id(.:format)
```

The problem is, it works in one area of my site just fine. Obviously its not setting the company_id properly, but when I set it manually, it doesn't seem to fix anything. I feel like I've tried every solution - but considering it works elsewhere in the site, I'm confused as to why it wouldnt work in one spot. (company IS defined - it's id is 2 in this case).

Comment: It's hard for me to understand what are you trying to do. May be you should specify `:url` with `company_news_index_path(company_id: company.id)` and `:method` with `:post` ? So you can also try `[company, @new_article]` as first param.

Comment: Try using company.id in <%= form_for(@new_article, {:url => [company, @new_article]}) do |news_form| %> which should look  like <%= form_for(@new_article, {:url => [company.id, @new_article]}) do |news_form| %>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though company was defined, and pass into the partial through an instance variable - and seems to be fine for other things in the page (acting normally). When I do something like:

```
<% @c = Company.find_by_id(company.id) %>
<% @new_article = @c.news.build %>
<%= form_for([@c, @new_article]) do |news_form| %>
```

It works fine. Very odd.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
company.news.build
```

instead of new. After that, you shouldn't need to do anything special:

```
<% @new_article = company.news.build %>
<%= form_for([company, @new_article]) do |news_form| %>
```

Comment: Can you add your routes definition please?

Answer (score -1):

you need a company.id <%= form_for(@new_article, {:url => [company.id, @new_article]}) do |news_form| %>